# How to fill specified detail grid with data on row click

Tags: javascript, html, grid, ag-grid

I am new to Ag-Grid. I am using it in JavaScript. I am learning about master/detail grids.
 I'm wondering if you are able to populate a detail grid with row data outside of the initial initialization. 
 For example, in my snippet I have this statement whit sets data for all the detail Grids:

```
getDetailRowData: function (params) {
      params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
    }
```

Now what if I didn't have that statement there in the grid options declaration, this would cause my detail grids to have no data. would it be possible to populate data in the detail grids outside of the initial grid options declaration, or possibly in a separate function??
code snippet below

```js
var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    // group cell renderer needed for expand / collapse icons
    { field: 'name', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' },
    { field: 'account' },
    { field: 'calls' },
    { field: 'minutes', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 'm'" },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  masterDetail: true,
  detailCellRendererParams: {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'callId' },
        { field: 'direction' },
        { field: 'number', minWidth: 150 },
        { field: 'duration', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'" },
        { field: 'switchCode', minWidth: 150 },
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    },
    getDetailRowData: function (params) {
      params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
    },
  },
  onFirstDataRendered: onFirstDataRendered,
};

function onFirstDataRendered(params) {
  // arbitrarily expand a row for presentational purposes
  setTimeout(function () {
    params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(1).setExpanded(true);
  }, 0);
}

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

  agGrid
    .simpleHttpRequest({
      url: 'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/master-detail-data.json',
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript example</title>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <style media="only screen">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }

            html {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            body {
                padding: 1rem;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-alpine" style="height: 100%;">
        </div>
        <script>var __basePath = './';</script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules@25.1.0/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="main.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear why do you want to update the data out side the grid configurations callback `getDetailRowData`. Could you please mention what are trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: Yes. The data for the detail grid is retrieved on a separate api call. I notice that for detail grids, when you populate the detail grid with data, it expects its data to be there in a single json along with the master grids data. It’s not the case for me I will need to make another api call to get the detail grid data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary at all to have all the data while initializing the master grid. You can  initialize master grid just with data which is necessary for master grid only.
`getDetailRowData` will be called only when a row is expanded, at that time you can make necessary API calls and update the details grid like below.

```
getDetailRowData: function (params) {
  // This can be API call
  Promise.resolve(data).then((res) => {
    params.successCallback(res);
  })
},
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        "name": "Nora Thomas",
        "account": 177000,
        "calls": 24,
        "minutes": 25.65
    },
    {
        "name": "Mila Smith",
        "account": 177001,
        "calls": 24,
        "minutes": 26.216666666666665
    }
];
const callRecords = {
    "177000": [
        {
            "name": "susan",
            "callId": 555,
            "duration": 72,
            "switchCode": "SW3",
            "direction": "Out",
            "number": "(00) 88542069"
        },
        {
            "name": "susan",
            "callId": 556,
            "duration": 61,
            "switchCode": "SW3",
            "direction": "In",
            "number": "(01) 7432576"
        },
    ],
    "177001": [
        {
            "name": "susan",
            "callId": 579,
            "duration": 23,
            "switchCode": "SW5",
            "direction": "Out",
            "number": "(02) 47485405"
        },
        {
            "name": "susan",
            "callId": 580,
            "duration": 52,
            "switchCode": "SW3",
            "direction": "In",
            "number": "(02) 32367069"
        }
    ]
}

var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    // group cell renderer needed for expand / collapse icons
    { field: 'name', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' },
    { field: 'account' },
    { field: 'calls' },
    { field: 'minutes', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 'm'" },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  masterDetail: true,
  detailCellRendererParams: {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'callId' },
        { field: 'direction' },
        { field: 'number', minWidth: 150 },
        { field: 'duration', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'" },
        { field: 'switchCode', minWidth: 150 },
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    },
    getDetailRowData: function (params) {
      Promise.resolve(callRecords[params.data.account]).then((res) => {
        params.successCallback(res);
      })
    },
  },
  onFirstDataRendered: onFirstDataRendered,
};

function onFirstDataRendered(params) {
  // arbitrarily expand a row for presentational purposes
  setTimeout(function () {
    params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(1).setExpanded(true);
  }, 0);
}

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
  gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>JavaScript example</title>
  <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <style media="only screen">
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    
    html {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    body {
      padding: 1rem;
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-alpine" style="height: 100%;">
  </div>
  <script>
    var __basePath = './';
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules@25.1.0/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="main.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```